# 2sxc: 404 error when adding content module

Tags: 2sxc

When I add a content module to a page I get a 404 error.

In the logbook I see the following entry

TabId:
PortalAlias:staging.2-le-marche.com/nl-nl
OriginalUrl:/nl-nl/desktopmodules/2sxc/api/view/Module/GetSelectableTemplates
Referer:http://staging.2-le-marche.com/desktopmodules/tosic_sexycontent/dist/dnn/ui.html?sxcver=8.5.1.26679
Url:http://staging.2-le-marche.com/nl-nl/desktopmodules/2sxc/api/view/Module/GetSelectableTemplates
UserAgent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/52.0.2743.116 Safari/537.36

Answer (score 0):

My guess is a miss-configuration of DNN and portal domains. That kind of thing can work for quite a while (pages do work) but the js-framework of dnn will then report a (slightly) different url than is actually in use, and end up pointing to a url which doesn't work.